# How should error callback logic interact with retry using android Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

Not clear on what type of error handling logic should be in place when Volley retry policy is set to say 3 times. Lets say the network is down and Volley is set to retry 3 times.  when will error callback be invoked? How can error handler detect that this is first attempt?  Or will it retry three times and only at end of third try deliver the Volley error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will report an error only after 3rd retry. Generally you can't detect attempt number. But there is some kind of hack: Volley will call your request's "getBody" method (and some others) on each retry. It also very use full to see Volley's sources.